# Qu'est-ce que ça veut dire "marre"?

Tags: vocabulaire

J'ai trouvé ce mot dans une phrase, mais je n'arrive pas à le comprendre.

> La maison est un grand chalet avec une petite marre à côté de la terrasse.

La seule traduction que j'ai trouvé de ce mot est *enough, be fed up with*.
Mais qu'est-ce que ça veut dire dans ce contexte ?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

C'est une faute d'orthographe. Le mot devrait être écrit avec un seul r :

> Mare (f) : Petite nappe d'eau dormante.

Une traduction anglaise de mare pourrait être *pond*.

Comment: Merci beaucoup! :D

Answer (score 3):

Marre avec 2 'r' peut être utilisé comme conjugaison du verbe se marrer (plus fort que rigoler) ou dans des phrases comme 'J'en ai marre ,ça suffit' ce qui va mieux pour 'be fed up with' je pense.